# Set up a server for testing email alert

Tags: java, email, testing

I want to set up a server for testing email alerts. Requirements are as follows.

Suppose the application under test will send email alerts to a certain email address. What needs to be tested is that the smtp server is able to receive it and the received content is correct.

So, how can I achieve above requirements?

BTW, I have no experience in doing this, but my basic idea is to create an SMTP server in java that receives emails and forwards what is received to the test suite. Is that the normal way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: You may use free unix/linux standard MTA/server server reconfigured to redirect all outgoing email to single (local) mailbox.  I am 100% sure `sendmail` can be configured in such way.  IMHO it is the best option if you use unix/linux anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BTW, I have no experience in doing this, but my basic idea is to create an SMTP server in java that receives emails and forwards what is received to the test suite. Is that the normal way to do this sort of thing?

Ermm.  No.  It sounds like a lot of effort for not much gain.

If you wanted to automate the testing, normal thing would be to:

- create "mock" objects for the email sending APIs you are using,
- look for an existing test framework for testing mail-sending capability,
- set up a test instance of a "real" mail server, and configure it to write the emails to some file that your tests can examine.

And in a situation like this, I'd be tempted to rely on hand testing (with a *real* mail server and a real mailbox) to test the final mail server integration.

Basically, attempting to code your own cut-down mail server in Java is likely to be an effort sink.  And besides, you have no way of knowing if your hypothetical server will behaves (sufficiently) correctly to be a valid test of your application.